# cannot parse the debug map for notification service target

Tags: xcode14.3.1

I am able to run my code and device but when I try to create archive I am facing error.

```
GenerateDSYMFile   
Cannot parse the debug map for notification service target 
No such file or Directory
```

**Solutions that I tried**

- Clean
- Xcode & System Restart
- Delete cocoapods & reinstall

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Enable Bitcode helped me with the issue.